# Unexpected Dilemma with Bottom Up Merge Sort

Tags: c

I just recently finished reading up on what the gist of bottom up merge sort was and in my opinion, it makes sense, but when I think of how to do the implementation it gets me a bit confused.

I know that we start off by combining adjacent pairs of elements, but how do we compare the size of the elements before merging them? Wouldn't this end up as a n^2 algorithim?

For example:

Lets say I have an array such as this:

```
int a[6] = {1,3,2,6,8,7};
```

Then I split it into size 1 (not really splitting, but looking at indexes I suppose)

```
{1}{3}{2}{6}**{8}{7}**
```

After that it becomes this:

```
{1,3}{2,6}**{7,8}**<<<<<<<< I am assuming we are using an if statement to arrange
switching 7 and 8 in the merge process only takes O(n)
```

HOWEVER,

How do I do the comparison on the next pass for this:

```
**{1,2,3,6}**{7,8}   >>>> Wouldn't I need a nested for loop to compare and sort?
```

In all the exmaples I read, they don't explain how they manage to compare it, all they say is merge it and show a picture of the 2 sub arrays magically sorting it self. I am working on this in C, and I need some guidance as to how to get it in order when I merge it. I can't think of any other way of sorting it but with a O(n^2) nested for loop after merging. If someone can show me how to do this, then I'll be happy as ever!

What I am trying to get at is, it won't be OlogN if I sort using an n^2 algorithm.

Comment: You copy the two sublists to a temp buffer.  Then you copy the elements back one at a time.  When you copy back, you simply compare the heads of the two lists to find out which is smaller, and copy that one back.  This takes O(N) time.

Answer (score 0):

Here's is a Bottom Up Merge right from [Wikipedia's Merge Sort Implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation):

```
BottomUpMerge(int A[], int iLeft, int iRight, int iEnd, int B[])
{
    int i0 = iLeft;
    int i1 = iRight;
    int j;

    /* While there are elements in the left or right lists */
    for (j = iLeft; j < iEnd; j++) {
        /* If left list head exists and is <= existing right list head */
        if (i0 < iRight && (i1 >= iEnd || A[i0] <= A[i1]))
        {
            B[j] = A[i0];
            i0 = i0 + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            B[j] = A[i1];
            i1 = i1 + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was never good at reading other people's code, can you explain to me what the variables are? I am also not understand that loooong if statement..Looks mind boggling.

Comment: @BeginnerC If you follow the link, it will be easier to understand in the context of its calling function `BottomUpSort` where A[] is the unsorted list and B[] is the output of the function.  It's very well commented.